# How to find error in php

Tags: php

I'm beginner for php and I'm coding on Notepad_++.  an error creating in my programming while updating/editing  any row from the table. When I changed something from the row and click on submit button then page return on  main page and nothing changed with without error shown, show I can't guess where is error.
suppose..- I have a table which name is Customer Details_tbl and I click on a row edit button, after click a page opening which name is add_customer_tbl and I trying to change some information of customer, after some changing,' I clicking on submit button and page return on Customer_detail_tbl page but no changing and no any error showing .. so my question is how to fix it..

```
$error="Failed to Update.". mysqli_error($db); //this code I already putted
```

Comment: If you are redirected after the error occurs, you lose the error message. The code you've written above (reading from `mysqli_error`) might be alright, but you should remove the redirect first

Comment: Instead of explaining your code, you should add all the relevant code into the question. We need to see the context of the above line.

Comment: .  when I was searching not founded any ans. related to this q. okay.. so dnt say It Duplicate ..plzzz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to view Error then you can do many ways:

1.) You can do it from PHP.INI

```
display_errors = on
```

2.) You can do it from error_reporting(1);

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(1);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?
```

3.) You can do it from ini_set('display_errors', 1);

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Set this in index.php

Answer (score 1):

first You should modify your php.ini with this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

and you can also Dumping Variables Before Send to db For debug

```
var_dump($yourvar);
die();
```

Comment: Dangerous to recommend "display_errors=on" without a clear caveat that this is for dev only.

Comment: Turn on Debug mode could be dangerous always

Answer (score -1):

Use it after declare php tag or show me your full code for clarification :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```